# Int object not iterable for .extend operator

Tags: python

```
AgeList = [0]

for i in range (5):
    age = int(input("Enter Age: "))
    if (age>=18):
        print("You're eligible to vote.")
    else:
        print(f"Wait {18-age} years to vote")
    AgeList = AgeList.extend(age)
print(AgeList)
```

throws this. I don't know how to fix this. tried doing AgeList + age but didn't work either; got just the last input returned. I've tried the other solution I've found but didn't work for me.

```
Wait 6 years to vote
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-1b9edf4fd144> in <module>
      7     else:
      8         print(f"Wait {18-age} years to vote")
----> 9     AgeList = AgeList.extend(age)
     10 print(AgeList)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+` operator needs to have `iterable`s in both sides:

```
AgeList += [age]
```

Comment: That will set `AgeList` to `None`. Also, it's better to use `append`, which is the function intended to use for adding a single element.

Comment: @interjay Correct, I edited the answer to use `+` instead

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is using `extend()`, where you should use `append()`.

Extend takes anything iterable, meaning a tuple, string, list etc,
whereas `append()` also takes anything non-iterable, meaning integers, floats, etc.